# File manager is not recognizing the pendrive after formatting

Tags: usb, format

I have just formatted a pendrive to convert it from a bootable usb to normal usb.

After the formatting process it is not recognized by the file manager but it is visible in disk utility.

[image: here]

What should be done in order to cause the file manager to recognize the pendrive?

Comment: Your pendrive space is not allocated. Run gparted to do it. You just need to click into you unallocate space and create a new one.

Comment: Try with **mkusb** according to this link, https://askubuntu.com/questions/953032/cannot-write-and-delete-files-on-usb-drive/953489#953489

Answer (score 2):

1. Click on the 3 lines in the top-left corner. And then in the `format disk` option.
2. In the open window, be sure to select `no partition`. And select the method to format the device.
3. After that, click in `additional partition options`(gears) and select to `format volume`.
4. Choose the label name you want, and then if you'd like to erase your data and, after that, the type of format you want.