# Check external disk power condition / current state, Ubuntu terminal

Tags: hard-drive, power-management, external-hdd

Somewhat relevant to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56270/how-can-i-spin-down-external-hard-drive), but is there a way to check if an external disk is already currently spun down (i.e. in idle state)?

I'd like to check a remote disk over SSH, so listening to the disk in person is not possible.

Running `sudo hdparm -C /dev/sdb` shows this is not supported on Western Digital

```
/dev/sdb:
APT: USB ID = xxxxxx...
APT: Unsupported device
...
 drive state is:  unknown
```

Is there another tool that can do this on Ubuntu 20? Thanks

Update: I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-1015-raspi aarch64) on Raspberry Pi 4.

Comment: Read `man smartctl`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @waltinator, we can use `smartctl` as part of `smartmontools`:

`sudo smartctl -n standby /dev/sdb`

If the device is in standby, it should return exit code (2).

Comment: Thanks for the command